# Why do most X keyboard layouts only use the right alt as a modifier key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've been typing in a language that requires use of the modifier key a lot lately, and I noticed it was starting to hurt my right hand from the weird contortions required to simultaneously press the right alt (Alt Gr) while typing keys on the right side of the keyboard. So I set up my layout to use both alts as modifier keys, which was easy and worked perfect, but it did make me wonder: why do most of the default keyboard layouts only use the right alt anyway? Is it just for historical reasons? If so, what are they?

xkb provides several options for what to use as a modifier keys. Here's what `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3` has to say about the option to use both alts:

```
// Either Alt key (while pressed) chooses the third shift level.
// (To be used mostly to imitate Mac OS functionality.)
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "alt_switch" {
  include "level3(lalt_switch)"
  include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

If that's how it works in Mac OS, then I like it! Why not copy it?

I did a quick search of both options in my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and I found 344 keyboard layouts that use `ralt_switch`, and only 4 that use both.

#### Edit 1:

In the process of researching this question I discovered one possible answer: it breaks all the keyboard shortcuts that used to use the left alt key! Though it seems one could get around that by making those shortcuts accept either alt key too... I'm still playing with this, and it may yet prove that this is actually worse overall for some reason, but in principle my question stands (if this is really how it works in Mac OS, presumably Apple figured out a way to get around all these potential problems that arise, and we could do whatever they do).

Comment: AltGr is for typing letters and symbols. Alt is for keyboard shortcuts to commands. Alt used to be more common than Ctrl, e.g. Alt+s = Save. But there's still things like Alt+1 = switch to tab 1, and Emacs editing shortcuts like Alt+f = forward word in apps that support that.

Comment: This didn't seem worth a whole edit, but I looked in and 3/4 of the layouts that use the dual alt option are for the HTC dream: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/T-Mobile_G1_launch_event_2.jpg

Comment: @Mikel Yes, I see that. I've never used a Mac extensively, but it seems like they don't have any issue with using both alts for both keyboard shortcuts and as key modifiers—why can't we have that too?

For example, it seems that on a Mac Option+f is ƒ, and Option+Command+f is "find," and that apparently seems to work fine.

Comment: FWIW, for now I've just moved L_Alt to the Menu key, and use both Alts as R_Alt, and that seems to work perfectly. Though I still think it should be possible to use Alt as a modifier and shortcut key, as apparently Apple computers do.